# Merging two tables under some conditions

Tags: sql, sas

I need some help with proc SQL. I have a table like this

```
ID1    ID2           DR1    DR2
  1    03/04/2009    158      0
  2    12/06/2009    214      0
  2    05/02/2009     59      0
  1    03/04/2009      0    158
  2    03/04/2009    225      0
```

and i would like to create a new table with each line where DR2 isn't null, and for each of these line, search if there is another line with the same ID1 and ID2 and with DR1 equal to the value of DR2.

For this example, it would give me this table :

```
ID1    ID2           DR1    DR2
  1    03/04/2009      0    158
  1    03/04/2009    158      0
```

I tried to do it in two step but without success :

```
data tmpTable;
    set Table;
    where DR2>0;
run;

proc sql;
    create table wanted as
    select * from tmpTable
    inner join Table on Table.ID1 = tmpTable.ID1 
                         and Table.ID2 = tmpTable.ID2 
                         and Table.DR1 = tmpTable.DR2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the query working, then you can just add your create table version of it.

It should be just a simple self-join based on opposite column values like I have below.

```
SELECT
      t1.d1,
      t1.id2,
      t1.dr1,
      t1.dr2
   from 
      Table t1
         JOIN Table t2
            ON t1.d1 = t2.d1
            AND t1.dr1 = t2.dr2
            AND t1.dr2 = t2.dr1
   where
         t1.dr1 > 0
      OR t2.dr2 > 0
```

I would ensure you have an index on (d1, dr1, dr2) for performance purposes.

You mention that you only want records where the DR2 HAS a value (not zero/null).  The where clause will make sure that AT LEAST one of the columns has a value.  So, in your example, it will find the 158/0  (zero in second column), but the inverse too (0,158) your qualifying DR2 not null.

The ONLY time both versions will be returned is when the inverse appears as the joined table too.

Answer (score 1):

You can just merge the file on itself with the correct where statements.

Note that `null` is `.` not `0` -- (Your data step is eliminating rows where dr2 = 0 making your result table impossible)

```
proc sql;
    create table wanted as
    select distinct * 
    from table_have a, table_have b
    where 
            a.id1 = b.id1
        and  
            a.ID2 = b.ID2
        and  
            a.DR2 = b.DR1
        and
            a.dr2 ne .
    ;
quit;
```